# Downloading a string asynchronously, UI freezes briefly

Tags: .net, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm writing an Xamarin.Forms app and I'm having some trouble making a request using async. The freezes temporarily when the network request is made when it really shouldn't. What am I doing wrong?

```
public RecipesView LatestRecipes
    (string searchTerm, long? fromTimestamp, int recordsPerPage, bool hasMoreRecords)
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.CookieContainer = Settings.cookies;

        string url = Settings.Default.baseUrl + "/Api/recipes/latest";
        Dictionary<string, string> queryString = new Dictionary<string, string> ();
        queryString.Add ("maxRecords", recordsPerPage.ToString());
        queryString.Add ("searchTerm", searchTerm);
        queryString.Add ("username", "");
        queryString.Add ("boardSlug", "");
        queryString.Add ("type", "json");

        string queryUrl = url + ToQueryString(queryString);

        string result = DownloadString (queryUrl, handler).Result;

        RecipesView view = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecipesView> (result);
        hasMoreRecords = view.HasMoreRecords;

        foreach (RecipeModel model in view.Records) {
            model.OriginalImageWidth = model.ImageWidth;
            model.OriginalImageHeight = model.ImageHeight;
        }

        return view;

    }

    public async Task<string> DownloadString(string url, HttpClientHandler handler)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler); // Xamarin supports HttpClient!

        Task<string> contentsTask = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url); // async method!

        // await! control returns to the caller and the task continues to run on another thread
        string contents = await contentsTask;

        return contents; // Task<TResult> returns an object of type TResult, in this case int
    }
```

Thanks,
Colin.

Comment: Your consumption of DownloadString is not async.  Calling .Result is waiting for the task to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With async/await, you need to go async all the way down.  So you should change your LatestRecipes method to be async as well.

```
public async Task<RecipesView> LatestRecipesAsync(string searchTerm, long? fromTimestamp, int recordsPerPage, bool hasMoreRecords)
{
// ... Your existing code ...
    string result = await DownloadString (queryUrl, handler);
// ... The rest of your code ...
}
```

Also, the recommended convention for async methods is to postfix the name with Async.

Comment: Ah, I see, so how far do I need to go back? So for the parent method do I add an await like 

RecipesView rv = await recipeService.LatestRecipes (searchTerm, fromTimestamp, maxRecords, hasMoreRecords);

and then add async to the method declaration too?

Comment: Go as far back up as you can.  In WinForms/WPF, you do `async void` on your event handlers and go async all the way down.  I would guess Xamarin has something similar.